# LIne too long error for hash - Rails Haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
= f.association :country, :collection => ProductValues.countries.map { |country| [country.name, country.id] }, :include_blank => "Select Country", :label => "Country", :selected => records.country_id ? records.country_id : crecord.country_id
```

When I commit my code I am getting **line too long** error. I can split the above code in multiple lines. How can I implement a best practise to avoid such an error in the above line.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to avoid calculation logic in view, one pattern usually used in Rails project is decorator pattern. This gem can be used to refactor using that pattern: https://github.com/drapergem/draper

An easy way to improve above code is to separate calculations into separate line

```
- country_map = ProductValues.countries.map { |country| [country.name, country.id] }
- selected = records.country_id ? records.country_id : crecord.country_id

= f.association :country, collection: country_map, include_blank: "Select Country", label: "Country", selected: selected
```

Comment: @Tal - Thanks. Still it is a long line